# Why genymotion stopped suddenly and not display? in android java

Tags: android-studio, virtualbox, genymotion

genymotion when i run it, it's window dosn't display and not openning but when open task manager it's in process
note : it was working but i restarted the PC and tapped on restart any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens after a Windows system upgrade. You need to remove Genymotion completely and re-install it. Follow the instructions from https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002815177-How-to-uninstall-Genymotion-Desktop-completely-purge-